# Dynamically scroll through tableView with scrollToRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll

I'd like to visually scroll through my whole tableView. I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to perform the scrolling. Instead it just runs through the loops. I inserted a dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) statement, thinking that that would ensure the view is refreshed before proceeding, but no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

```
func scrollThroughTable() {
    for sectionNum in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections() {
        for rowNum in 0..<tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(sectionNum) {

            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: rowNum, inSection: sectionNum)
            var cellTemp = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
            if cellTemp == nil {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Simply use scrollToRowAtIndexPath() with animation. To do so I had to create a getIndexPath() function to figure out where I want to scroll. Has more or less the same effect as scrolling through the whole table if I pass it the last element of my tableView.

If you want it to happen slower with more scrolling effect, wrap it inside UIView.animateWithDuration() and play with 'duration'. You can even do more animation if you want in its completion block. (No need to set an unreliable sleep timer, etc.)

```
func animateReminderInserted(toDoItem: ReminderWrapper) {
    if let definiteIndexPath = indexPathDelegate.getIndexPath(toDoItem) {
        self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(definiteIndexPath, atScrollPosition: .Middle, animated: true)
    }
}
```